# Using mfirstuc with hyperref

Tags: hyperref, mfirstuc

I need to change the first letter in part of a link to uppercase. While I can easily do this for the label with `\makefirstuc`, I can't make it to work in the link itself. In the MWE below, the label is correctly changed from `testname` to `Testname` but the link becomes `https://someaddresss/\makefirstuc {testname}.py`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mfirstuc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\addlink}[1]
{
\href{https://someaddress/\makefirstuc{#1}.py}{\makefirstuc{#1}.py} 
}

\begin{document}
    
    \addlink{testname}
    
    Label is changed as expected from \verb+testname+ to \verb+Testname+.
    
    Link stays \verb+https://someaddresss/\makefirstuc {testname}.py+
\end{document}
```

MWE output is:

> Testname.py
>
> Label is changed as expected from testname to Testname.
>
> Link stays https://someaddresss/\makefirstuc {testname}.py

I suspect there is an easy answer, but I cannot find it... Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{hyperref} 

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN\texttitlecasefirst\text_titlecase_first:n
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\href{https://someaddress/\texttitlecasefirst{blub}.py}{\texttitlecasefirst{blub}.py} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Cool, that works, thanks for the super quick solution. Could you point me to an explanation what this code does?

Comment: it uses another (expandable) command provided by latex directly.